# svchost.exe crash on wake up

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, event-log

Lately whenever I wake up my laptop from sleep `(S3)` I get a series of errors (generated by a host process failing)

I haven't been able to figure out why this happens but I know which host process fails and was wondering if someone had some insight on why this keeps occuring 99% of the time when my laptop wakes up.

here's the host process error

> Faulting application svchost.exe_SysMain, version 6.0.6001.18000, time stamp 0x47919291, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e0421d, exception code 0xc0000006, fault offset 0x000000000005a02d, process id 0x1738, application start time 0x01cae656279b1010.

and here are some services that fail because of that host

> The Windows Audio Endpoint Builder service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> The Wired AutoConfig service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 0 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> The ReadyBoost service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> The Human Interface Device Access service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 120000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> The Network Connections service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 100 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> The Program Compatibility Assistant Service service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> The Superfetch service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.

Anyways I think you get the point, there are a few more. It got really annoying to wait for those services to restart so I created a batch file that does it automatically whenever the wlan stops but this is just a temporary solution

I'm using `Vista x64` on a `Studio XPS 1640`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason the problem stopped on it's on, it might have been something I uninstalled that fixed the issue, can't be 100% sure though since I wasn't monitoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this is an error on hibernate file, or on virtual memory file.

I recommend to delete and recreate them, stating from hibenate file.

Clear and your temporary directory just in case.

How you can do that ? because they are locked.

On control panel, on power manager on hibernate, remove the "Enable Hibernation", then make a restart of your computer, then delete the hibernate file from C:\ (if exist it will be hidden and system if I remember well).

Then enable again hibernate, restart and do your test - if not corrected, then take one more try with the virtual memory.

Disable all virtual memory, then restart, then clear possible file of it, then re-enabled it again.

Comment: tried all of that and still get the same error. Doesn't the hiberfil.sys get overwritten whenever the computer goes into hibernation anyways, so deleting and re-creating it shouldn't do much, same for the page file. 
This problem has me stumped... any other suggestions?

Comment: @Serge its seems that hibernation is not fully delete and recreating, every system sleeps, but keep some information in the header or in some place on it - This is from my experience, and not really know what happens - just in my case solve the problem. In you case not help :( sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I should have probably mentioned that it wakes up from sleep `S3` and not hibernation.